# How precise are Wolfram Alpha's mathematical calculations?

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I recently started learning about floating point arithmetic and a how computers have limited precision when dealing with such calculations.

**To what degree of accuracy can Wolfram alpha output computations?**

I was hoping to check the accuracy of some calculations in C++ by comparing them to answers outputted by Wolfram Alpha.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When requesting sqrt(2) with "more digits" Wolfram Alpha outputs

[image: sqrt(2)]

which far exceeds the accuracy of double-precision floating point variables (in which sqrt(2) is 1.4142135623730951).

WA is also smart about the organization of computation, preventing the loss of significant digits. For example, [sqrt(10^100+1)-10^50](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(10%5E100%2B1)-10%5E50) outputs a correct value, slightly less than 5e-51. Straightforward execution of the same computation is likely to return exactly 0.

So, the answer is yes: it is reasonable to check the accuracy of floating point computations using Wolfram Alpha.